# Image not posting by base64 string on json

Tags: ios, iphone, json, base64

I am Posting a image on Server By json Post Webservice.I have to upload the image on base 64 .I am encoding my image to base 64 string but the Image is not posting on the server and not other things.There is No problem with the webservice.The image is uploading successfully in android.

```
selectedImage=[[NSData alloc]initWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:selectedImage forKey:@"image"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
strImage=[[NSString alloc]init]; 
strImage = [selectedImage base64Encoding];
strImage=[strImage stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"strImage %@",strImage);
/*
NSData  *b64DecData = [Base64 decode:strImage];
NSLog(@"strImage %@",strImage);
[bttnimage setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithData:b64DecData] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
*/


NSString *post=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"name=%@&aboutMe=%@&chatId=%@&gender=%@&lookingFor=%@&city=%@&birthdate=%@&anniversarydate=%@&number1=%@&number2=%@&number3=%@&image=%@",[txtProfileName.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],[txtComment.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],[appDelegate.chatid stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],[bttnGender.titleLabel.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],[bttnLookingfor.titleLabel.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],[txtPlace.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],[dobLabel.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],[anniversaeyLabel.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],[txtNumber.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],[txtNum1.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],[txtNum2.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],strImage];

NSLog(@"post %@",post);
NSData * postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];

NSString * postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *latrequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.xyzAbc.org/iphone/updateProfile.php?%@",post];

NSLog(@"url %@",url);

[latrequest setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
Connection=[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:latrequest delegate:self];   
[latrequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[latrequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[latrequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[latrequest setHTTPBody:postData];
[latrequest release];

NSLog(@"latre %@",latrequest);
```

the code is above Please Let me know if I am missing something. Please any one Help me with that.

Comment: Where is your JSON? Apparently, you are using form-urlencoded parameters. So, what are you trying to accomplish? Sending a JSON or a form-urlencoded parameter string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image posting is different in iOS when we compare it with Android.

And in iOS  do this formate

```
 NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"********************/web-services/register_user.php?firstname=%@&lastname=%@&email=%@&password=%@&location=india&device=IPHONE",details.fname,details.lname,details.emailAddress,details.password];
    // urlString=[urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];



UIImage *image=details.pic;
NSData *imageData =UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.1);
double my_time = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)(my_time)];
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", @"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"profile_pic\"; filename=\"", imageName, @".jpg\"\r\n\""];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:string] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString*s11=   [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *responseDictionary1;
responseDictionary1 = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:s11 error:nil];
```

////////
This will fix issue

Regards
Charan Giri

Comment: sorry friend it does not help.

Comment: if the web service done by PHP they need to write different structure for receiving image....

Comment: <?php
$uploaddir = 'uploads/';
$file = basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

echo "file=".$file; //is empty, but shouldn't

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo $file;
}
else {
    echo "error";
}
?>

Comment: make sure the file name you are sending and they are using should be same

Comment: please ask you PHP/ Web services team to write the code which is mentioned in previous comment

Answer (score 2):

First add `Base64.h` and `Base64.m` files to your project. The following method will return Base-64 string from UIImage.

```
-(NSString*)getBase64StringfromImage:(UIImage*)image{

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,90);
    NSString *ImgStr=[Base64 encode:imageData];
    ImgStr=[ImgStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];
    return ImgStr;
}
```

Comment: yes i already convert the file to base 64 and i correct i check it by chandging it back to UIIMage and it is working fine.I think i have problem in json request???

Comment: Thanks! You saved me...`[ImgStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];`